# How to send notifications even when the page is closed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, service-worker

I want to make an AJAX request every 10 seconds, even when the page is closed, to send notifications like Facebook, when it sends notifications with the tab closed.

I guest I can accomplish this with service workers. I have tried doing this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
}
```

But I don't know how to send an AJAX call in `sw.js`.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: the problem is how to run ajax when the page not open, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: Maybe you're interested in Web Push Notifications https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox?as=u#w_upgraded-notifications

Comment: Have you tried the [fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)?